# Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I am trying to install Flutter Enviroment and I found this error when I use this command:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.43.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

So When I use `flutter doctor --android-licenses` I found this error also:

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

When I tried to run this command `C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update` I found this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
```

So any one knows hoe to solve this problem

Comment: Did you try running the command you are told to run?

Comment: @Amongalen Which command you mean?

Comment: what you get when you run C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
command ?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the directory `C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\`
and then write the command:

```
sdkmanager --update
```

After that, run:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reinstall flutter.
You should just go to android studio->sdk manager-> sdk tools-> clear tick from Hide Obsolete Packages and tick Android Sdk tools (Obsolete) in order to install.
Finally it will be installed and you will able use flutter.
P.s. Don't forget to run to flutter doctor)
[The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWzMz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate in cmd to the needed folder. I think it was:

```
cd C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

After this run the flutter doctor command.